# problems with prefs.get and set ImageJ Macro

Tags: macros, preferences, imagej

I'm trying to write a macro to save preferences and read them after closing and reopening ImageJ.

The saving works, but the macro isn't reading the file. Moreover when I try to use one of these two lines an error occurs that the variable "Prefs" is unknown.

```java
int myNumber = Prefs.get("my.persistent.number", 0);

Prefs.savePreferences();
```

What am I doing wrong? please help me :-)

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the [ImageJ macro language](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html)? Your code looks more like Java code.

Comment: yeah I'm sure, found it in a tutorial and following links http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Making-a-panel-of-buttons-in-a-macro-plugin-td3692757.html    http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Re-How-to-save-macro-variables-values-in-a-text-file-td5001804.html and as I said, saving preferences works, but not retrieving. Even not when I try  call("ij.Prefs.get", "myVariableKey", "defaultValue");

Comment: What do you mean by "saving preferences works"? How did you check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ImageJ macro language itself does not support storing custom preferences. (Only the set of built-in options (accessible via *Edit > Options* in the menu) can be [saved](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#saveSettings), [restored](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#restoreSettings) and [adjusted](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#setOption).) You need to resort to calling the Java class via `call("ij.Prefs.get", "my.persistent.number", "0");`.

- The following ImageJ macro works in an up-to-date Fiji/ImageJ installation:

```bsh
myNumber = call("ij.Prefs.get", "my.persistent.number", "0");
print(myNumber);
call("ij.Prefs.set", "my.persistent.number", 3);
```

In the first run, it prints `0`; every following run will print `3`; after restarting Fiji, it will print `3` again. In case it does not work for you even after updating to the newest version, please report a bug via *Help > Report a bug*, which will also submit essential information about your installation to the developers to help them fix the issue.

- Using one of the many [scripting languages](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_Help) however, you can access the [`ij.Prefs`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/Prefs.html) java class directly, as you are trying to do it. Just do not forget to *import* the class before using it. This is an example Javascript:

```js
importClass(Packages.ij.Prefs);

myNumber = Prefs.get("my.persistent.number", 0);
Prefs.set("my.persistent.number", myNumber);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, copied the Import class, mine was wrong. importClass - udefined identifier.... and "prefs" is still not known variable..

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify the situation, whether you use the macro language (first option) or Javascript (second option).